# How to restructure characters in custom format?

Tags: r, split, character

i want to convert "hello,world" into vector as "hello","world"

i tried splitting as below:

```
c<- "hello,world"

spl<-unlist(strsplit(c, ","))
```

but I am getting result as below:

"hello" "world"

I want my result as:

```
"hello","world"
```

Comment: Do you want: `dput(spl)` ?

Comment: please provide sample ans output with `dput(mydata)` and `dput(myanswer)`, so the answers will actually provide what you are looking for. Also, make your sample data a address all possible issues. So no `a,b,c,d` of you actually need `hello,world` to be splitted...

Comment: @Wimpel i have modified question for better understanding now can you help me ?

Comment: not really.. please use `dput(myoutout)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
> cat(gsub("(\\w+)", "\"\\1\"", s), "\n")
"a","b","c","d"
```

**Data**

```
s <- "a,b,c,d"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this is working for single character but, what if we have data as s<- "hello,world" and i want as "hello","world"

Comment: @SushantShelke Use `strsplit(s,",")[[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

## First make your string to a vector as follows.

```
cc<- str_split(cc,",")[[1]]
```

#Then use **shQuote()** to make each element of vector quoted string and then use **paste()** to make them comma separated.

```
print(paste(shQuote(cc), collapse=", "))
```